# How to serve static file (json) to a explicit path

Tags: iis, model-view-controller, windows-server-2016

I want to add a path `mysite.com/_this` when a request for this path is called I want to serve the `json` file that's under Sites/MySite/Content.

The caveat is I cannot implement this via code change. I need a way to implement this setup using the IIS CLI.

I have found the following article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing, but it's a little cryptic and hard to follow.

Windows: Window Server 2016 (1607)

IIS: 10.0.14393.0

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the right solution for your issue is iis URL rewrite module.

If you did not install the url rewrite module you could download from the below link:

[URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

then add a rule in web.config file:

```
<rule name="Json Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="([\S]+[.](json))" />
   <action type="Rewrite" url="folderpath/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

You can do all these changes in the IIS Manager UI, but if you want to script them, look into the [PowerShell IIS cmdlets](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790599.aspx).